# Pre-populate DevDemon Form Fields?

Tags: forms, devdemon

I'd like to be able to pre-populate some DevDemon form fields depending on the URL. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What does your URL look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jQuery. You'll just need to know the id of the field you are pre-populating.

```
   {if segment_1 == "foo"}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('#ddform_21').val("Value 1");
      $('#ddform_46').val("Value 2");
      $('#ddform_87').val("Value 3");
    });
    </script>
    {/if}
```